# Which java collection to use?

Tags: java, collections

I'm having trouble deciding which java collection would fit my scenario best. Currently, I'm reading in a record that gives me an 'account number' and a 'customer name' values.

Based on these values, I need to search through another file based upon the account number and customer name given from the first file. The problem is that account number is not unique in the second file, so I need to search using both account number and customer name.

Instead of opening, reading, searching, closing the second file for every record I read from the first file, I'd like to read the entire file into a collection and use the Collections binary search to locate the associated record in the second file.

Is there a certain type of collection that would fit this purpose best (if any at all)?

Comment: Account number and customer are unique together? This way you can use map and complex key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have sufficient memory, I would probably use a [`HashMap<AccountIdentifier, CustomerRecord>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Where `CustomerRecord` is an object that contains the record you where looking for.

And then create a key class:

```
public class AccountIdentifier {
    public String accountNumber;
    public String customerName;

    public AccountIdentifier(String accountNumber, String customerName) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
        this.customerName = customerName;
    }
    public int hashCode() {
        return (accountNumber+"#"+customerName).hashCode();
    }

    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if(!(obj instanceof AccountIdentifier)) return false;
        else {
            AccountIdentifier id = (AccountIdentifier)obj;
            return accountNumber.equals(id.accountNumber) && customerName.equals(id.customerName);
        }
    }
}
```

So then you'd have to preload your second file in memory by reading each record and creating an instance of `CustomerRecord` with the data it contains, and also a `AccountIdentifier` to put in your `Map`:

`theMap.put(accountIdentifier, customerRecord);`

When comes the time to search, and you've got an accountNumber and customerName from the first file, then do:

```
AccountIdentifier accountIdentifier = new AccountIdentifier(accountNumber, customerName);
CustomerRecord record = theMap.get(accountIdentifier);
```

Final comment, if your file is too big to fit in memory, then you should consider using a cache library like [ehcache](http://ehcache.org).

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to create an object which contains both the account number and customer name.  Then you can read in your customer file in to the a `Map<CustomerInfo, FileInfo>`.  Here, `CustomerInfo` is your object which contains just the customer name and account number, and `FileInfo` is your object which contains all of the information read from the file.  Now you can do simple lookups against the map.

Note that you will need to ensure that `CustomerInfo` implements `hashCode()` and `equals()` for this to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think this has more to do on how you define your record than the actual collection.

You can create a `Comparator` that compares two records, and basically takes into account the id and name, if these match, you assume it's the same record.

Based on this, you can use the comparator you defined to search an `ArrayList` (for instance) of records for those who match your criteria.

The binary search is only helpful if you're returning only **one** match, as you can see by the method signature, **and** you need to sort the `Collection` prior to calling the binary search.

So, summing up:

- Define a `Comparator` that takes two `Record` objects and checks if they have the same id/name.
- Load all the Records into an `ArrayList`, for instance.
- Sort them.
- Call `Collections.binarySearch` with your sorted collection and your custom comparator.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it even faster?

Create a class Customer:

```
 public class Customer {
     private final int accountNumber;
     private final String customerName;

     public Customer (int accountNumber, String customerName) {
          this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
          this.customerName = customerName;
     }
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
          //check if accountNumber and customerName are equal
     } 
     public int hashCode() {
          return 13*accountNumber + 31*customerName.hashCode();
     }
 }
 public class CustomerBucket() {
     private final int forAccountNumber;
     private Map<String, Customer> map = HashMap<String, Customer>();
     public CustomerBucket(int forAccountNumber) {
         //...
     }
     public boolean equals(Object o) {
         return o.forAccountNumber == this.forAccountNumber;
     }
     public int hashCode() {
         return forAccountNumber;
     }
 }
 public class AccountSearcher {
     private final Set<CustomerBucket> set = new HashSet<CustomerBucket>();
     public Customer getCustomer(int accountNumber, String name) {
         return set.get(accountNumber).get(name);
     }
 }
```

That way you can search records in almost O(1). This approach also gives you the capabilities to search for accountNumbers (and return a list of names associated with that number).